# Reflection.emit System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I'm new to reflection.emit and have been trying to produce the following c# code:

```
public class RepositoryWrapper
{
    public void CallRepositoryMethod(IAddressRepository repository, Address address)
    {
        repository.NODE_I_NodeExtendedDetails_Address3(address.NodeId);
    }
}
```

Here is the il Representation of it:

```
    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.1
    IL_0002: ldarg.2
    IL_0003: callvirt instance int32 ReflectionServices.Node::get_NodeId()
    IL_0008: callvirt instance void ReflectionServices.IAddressRepository::NODE_I_NodeExtendedDetails_Address3(int32)
    IL_000d: nop
    IL_000e: ret
```

And here is my code used to create it:

```
 internal static void Generate(this System.Reflection.Emit.ILGenerator @this, Type target,string method,Type instance)
        {

        var methodToCall = target.GetMethod(method);
        var methodParams = methodToCall.GetParameters();
        var instanceProperties = instance.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        var orderedProperties = (from mp in methodParams
                              join p in instanceProperties
                              on mp.Name.ToLower() equals p.Name.ToLower()
                              select p).ToArray();

        //add properties to the string builder

        //load the object reference onto the stack sothat we can access its methods
        @this.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
        @this.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        @this.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2);

            var property = orderedProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "NodeId");
            if (property != null)
            {
                var getMethod = property.GetGetMethod();
                @this.Emit(getMethod.IsVirtual ? OpCodes.Callvirt : OpCodes.Call, getMethod);

            }


        //call method 
            @this.Emit(methodToCall.IsVirtual ? OpCodes.Callvirt : OpCodes.Call, methodToCall);
            @this.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
        //return from function
        @this.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        }
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
Result StackTrace:  
at ReflectionServices.Repository.NODE_I_NodeExtendedDetails3_Address40807399(Repository      target, Address )
```

here is the generated il:

```
nop
ldarg.1
ldarg.2
call instance int32 ReflectionServices.Node::get_NodeId()
callvirt instance void            
ReflectionServices.Repository::
                               NODE_I_NodeExtendedDetails3_Address(int32)
nop
```

ret

Can anybody see what the issue is i'm stuck?

thanks

here is my dll and method as requested:

```
 public sealed class ReflectionEmitWithDebuggingMethodGenerator
{
    private AssemblyBuilder Assembly { get; set; }
    private ModuleBuilder Module { get; set; }
    private AssemblyName Name { get; set; }

    public ReflectionEmitWithDebuggingMethodGenerator()
        : base()
    {
        this.Name = new AssemblyName() { Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") };
        this.Assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
            this.Name, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave,@"C:\Users\darren\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\UnityInjection");
        this.AddDebuggingAttribute(this.Assembly);
        this.Module = this.Assembly.DefineDynamicModule(this.Name.Name + ".dll", true);
    }
   public Action<TObject, TInstance> Generate<TObject, TInstance>(Type target, string methodN, Type instanceType)
    {
        var type = this.Module.DefineType(target.Namespace + "." + target.Name);
        var methodName = methodN + target.GetHashCode().ToString();
        var method = type.DefineMethod(methodName, MethodAttributes.Static | MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(void), new Type[] { target, instanceType });
        method.DefineParameter(1, ParameterAttributes.In, "target");
        method.DefineParameter(2, ParameterAttributes.In, "instance");

        ILGenerator.Generate(method.GetILGenerator(), target,methodN,instanceType);

        var createdType = type.CreateType();

        var createdMethod = createdType.GetMethod(methodName);
        return (Action<TObject, TInstance>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<TObject, TInstance>), createdMethod);
    }


}
```

Comment: You're getting the error when calling into the generated assembly, right? Have you compared the generated IL with the IL you're modeling?

Comment: Yes thats right I get the error when executing the Function. I have updated the post with the generated Il

Comment: How are you checking the generated IL? Are you dumping the assembly to disk and then opening it with something like Reflector?

Comment: No I'm writing it out to a file so I can use it to debug

Comment: What does PEVerify say about the generated assembly?

Comment: Hi svick, i dont seem to get or cant find the dll that is created

Comment: I have solved my problem the issue after running PEVerify on the assembly. The error was unrecognized argument, so I changed  @this.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); and @this.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2); to  @this.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); @this.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); i'm guessing this is because it wasn't a member call? can anyone elaberate? svick if you put your suggestion as an answer I will mark it  correct.

Comment: @Code Junkie my answer explains why your original code didn't work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing the compiled and the emitted output, there's only one difference:

Compiled:

```
callvirt instance int32 ReflectionServices.Node::get_NodeId()
```

Emitted:

```
call instance int32 ReflectionServices.Node::get_NodeId()
```

The type you're calling `int32 get_NodeId()` on is `ReflectionServices.Node`, but the type of the object you're passing into the method you're trying to replicate is `Address`. This leads me to believe that the property accessor defined on `ReflectionServices.Node` must be called virtually, perhaps because it inherits from another class (or implements an interface) that declares that property before `ReflectionServices.Node` implements it.

When you're emitting that line of code, simply call it virtually:

```
@this.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, getMethod);
```

---

**EDIT: In light of the further provided code, here's the *real* solution.**

So, you have a problem with the fundamentals of how you're implementing the interface:

```
var method = type.DefineMethod(methodName, MethodAttributes.Static | Method...
//                                                          ^^^^^^
```

Interface methods are not static; they're instance members. Thus, you first need to remove `MethodAttributes.Static` from the attributes flag upon creating the `MethodBuilder`.

Second, when you go to return this function, you're going to have to include a *target object*, which is the instance upon which the method is called. To do that, you can use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) to call the default-generated constructor and give you an instantiated object to use as the target. Replace the final line of your `Generate` method with these lines to achieve that.

```
var activatedObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

return (Action<TObject, TInstance>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    typeof(Action<TObject, TInstance>), activatedObject, createdMethod);
```

Comment: You are right the Address class inherits from Node which has the NodeId property. I tried your Change and just called the OpCodes.Callvirt but it still has the same error...

Comment: Well, if the generated IL matches up, something else must be the problem. Can you amend your post to include your calls to `DefineType` and `DefineMethod`?

Comment: What about the second argument?

Comment: after that line returns i call this:

Comment: ((Action<TObject, TInstance>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<TObject, TInstance>), createdMethod))(repository,address);

Comment: it means I can cache the function, i cant get it to work if I remove the static as you mentioned?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask. I ran the code (including my changes) and got the expected results... what are you trying to do now?

Comment: I have marked this as correct as it does fix the issue, however the fix for my issue was to change the load arg param as I want a static method.